# Mocha callback test omitted

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, mocha.js

```
describe 'app', ->
    it 'should be called by 2', (done) ->
        f 1, (x) ->  
            console.log 'Hi, callback!'
            (x).should.eql 2
            done()

f = (x, g) -> setTimeout g, 5000, x
```

The test above was run, but the console didn't log, so the callback was omitted, the test  faked passing.

Why did Mocha `#done` not wait for the delayed callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mocha default test timeout is 2000ms. Your test is timing out.

Use `this.timeout(5000);` within the `it` block to change the timeout for the test, or within the `describe` block to change the timeout for that suite.

See the docs [**here**](http://mochajs.org/#usage) and [**here**](http://mochajs.org/#suite-specific-timeouts).